# Heroku how to update git remotes after project rename

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, git-remote

I already renamed my project to PROJECT_NAME on Heroku and should I update project git remotes,

### This is Heroku guide:

```
$ git remote rm heroku
$ heroku git:remote -a PROJECT_NAME
```

But when I run the first command, I'm getting this error:

```
fatal: No such remote: heroku
```

Comment: What happens when you run the second command?

Comment: Now I realized why it was giving me this error, tnx for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first command `git remote rm heroku` will remove your local direction repository git remotes were linked to your online Heroku repository and it will continue without any error.

But if Heroku git remotes not already made or it was deleted, the terminal will show you this error: `fatal: No such remote: heroku`

Then you should create Heroku git remotes with the second command: 
`heroku git:remote -a PROJECT_NAME`.

This explanation applies to any git remotes, not just Heroku